# Selenium IDE: this.browserbot.getUserWindow().typeList.filter returns error on IE8

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, ide

I have faced with following trouble during working with Selenium.
I need to verify that some value exists in list and I use the following code:

assertEval
    this.browserbot.getUserWindow().typeList.filter(function(v) { return v[0] === 'Type_${r_suffix}'; })[0][0];
    Type_${r_suffix}

This works file on Firefox, but on IE 8 returns error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Could someone have an idea where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

As the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) say, the `filter()` method is available only for IE9 and above.

Your're just using a too new technology. Filter it manually using a `for` loop or insert the code for `Array.prototype.filter` (from the MDN) to have access to it.